# Reset input with materialize.css und jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, materialize

I want to clear an input field using

```
$('#test').val('');
```

The field itself getting cleared but the highlighting from Materialize.css stays like it's still filled.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrPNKd

Using ...

```
$('#form')[0].reset();
```

... is no option for me. I only want to reset one single input field not the whole form.

Did anyone have an idea?

Thanks

// EDIT

Found a solution:

```
$('#test').val('').removeClass('valid');
M.updateTextFields();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the class `active` from the label element next to your `<input>`:

```
$('#test').val('');
$('#test').next().removeClass('active');
```

The [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method is used to select the `<label>` element as it is the immediately following sibling of the `<input>` element.

Comment: It works nearly perfekt. Like using M.updateTextFields();
But it's got still the green underline from the Validation. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it - $('#test').removeClass('valid'); was the key

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...it's bit long but it works!

In Blade View

```
<div class="input-field testValidator">
    <input name="test" id="test" type="text" data-length="8">
    <label for="test">test</label>
</div>
```

In jQuery

```
  $("input[name='test']").val('');
  $('.testValidator span').text('');
```

The logic is changing the text in input-field's span wording from "??/8" to ""

Answer (score 0):

I´ve detected the text area has an style that grows based on the number of lines you type inside of the text area.

In my case de default in-line style was as follows..  style="height: 43px";

So, to reset the text area to the original Height i performed the following with JQuery

```
$('#test').val('');
$('#test').css('height', '43px');
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [correct element structure](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) then three things change when you fill in a materialize form:

1) The input value

2) The label position

3) The input style (validation class)

This is an unfilled input:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
     <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
</div>
```

And filled in:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
     <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate valid">
     <label for="last_name" class="active">Last Name</label>
</div>
```

To get back to the original state we need to remove the .valid class from the input (which adds green border-bottom), the .active class from the label (which shifts it up) and then the text input:

```
jQuery('#last_name').removeClass('valid').val('');
jQuery('label[for=last_name]').removeClass('active')
```